# Listview views don't take requested width in Android

Tags: android, listview, baseadapter

I'm having an issue in which I place two views inside a LinearLayout which is the row of a listview, and the items don't take the width they should.

The result appears as if the first inserted element takes a width equal to `wrap_content`, and the second takes whatever width is left. My guess is that these child views are drawn before the parent LinearLayout is and thus can't respect the `layout_width` and `layout_weight` params I'm setting, but I can't get any further than that.

Since each of the two inserted views (which are created from the same layout xml) has `android:layout_weight="1"` and `android:layout_width="0dp"`, I'm expecting each to take about 50% of the available width.

I'm working with a custom "Team" object which via a getListView() method, returns a View that will be placed inside the LinearLayout which in turn gets placed inside the listview row.

I'm also working with a listview and an custom adapter that extends BaseAdapter. The following is the getView implementation:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.node_category_listview_row, parent, false);
    } else {
        ((LinearLayout)convertView).removeAllViews();
    }

    for (Team team : displayArray.get(position)) {
        final View v = team.getListView(context);
        ((LinearLayout)convertView).addView(v);
    }

    return convertView;
}
```

The R.layout.node_category_listview_row file is the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

The team's layout (only top part is included) is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="@dimen/node_default_spacing"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    tools:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <!-- The outer LinearLayout exists for the layout_weight=1 value -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="@dimen/node_default_spacing"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="100dp">
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/node_base_listview_style_one_image"
                tools:src="@drawable/listview_placeholder"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:contentDescription="@string/empty" />
            <TextView
                tools:text="December 29th"
                android:id="@+id/node_base_listview_style_one_date"
                android:textSize="@dimen/node_default_text_title_large_size"
                android:textColor="#fff"
                android:layout_margin="@dimen/node_default_spacing"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:textAllCaps="true"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
        </FrameLayout>

        <TextView
            tools:text="Title goes here"
            android:id="@+id/node_base_listview_style_one_title"
            android:textSize="@dimen/node_default_text_title_size"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/node_default_spacing"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/node_default_spacing"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/node_default_spacing"
            android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
            android:maxLines="2"
            android:textAllCaps="true"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <TextView
                tools:text="Subname goes here"
                android:id="@+id/node_base_listview_style_one_subtitle"
                android:textSize="@dimen/node_default_text_text_size"
                android:layout_margin="@dimen/node_default_spacing"
                android:maxLines="2"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
            <TextView
                tools:text="3 miles"
                android:id="@+id/node_base_listview_style_one_distance"
                android:textSize="@dimen/node_default_text_text_size"
                android:layout_margin="@dimen/node_default_spacing"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
            </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Let me know if you need more code. Any tips are appreciated!

Comment: add node_category_listview_row complete code

Comment: @USKMobility `node_category_listview_row` is already complete. It's just an empty `LinearLayout` that will contain the other two views.

Comment: You're missing the end of the "teams" layout - could you add it?
What's the `weightSum` of the outer `LinearLayout`?

Comment: @Darwind Sure, just a second. However you can see the outer `LinearLayout`s weight: `android:layout_weight="1"` and `android:layout_width="0dp"` That first `LinearLayout` you see is the outer `ViewGroup`.

Comment: But the outer `LinearLayout` shouldn't have a `weight`, but a `weightSum` and the inner items should have a `weight` of 1 each if you want to make them have the same size. The `weightSum` on the outer layout is not required - the `weight` on the inner items are however required.

Comment: Hi @Darwind, lets see if I understand: `R.layout.node_category_listview_row` is the outer `LinearLayout`. It currently does not have a `android:weightSum` value nor a `android:weight` value. I tried adding a weightSum=2 (since the two inserted layouts (one for each team) have a weight of 1) but it's still not working.

Comment: Have a look at this pastebin: http://pastebin.com/9CaphC1m
I have a `ListView` with an outer layout that hosts my 2 buttons in each row. Everything is working fine. As you're not sharing all the code, it's to debug to figure out what the issue is.

Comment: Just included the full layout. I saw your code and it seems simple enough. I'll try creating a `LayoutParam` object via code like you do and see if that works. I noticed that you don't use `weightSum` also, although according to the docs that should be fine as long as you use `layout_weight`